# Electron How to set a device type user agent

Tags: webview, electron, user-agent

I am making a web browser using electron, and I was wondering if there is a way to make electron report specific user agent information to trick websites into thinking they are being rendered on a phone rather than on a desktop. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

1) Using the `BrowserWindow` object

```
win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
win.loadURL('http://my-website/foo.html', {
    userAgent: 'MyFakeAgent/1.0'
});
```

2) Inside a `<webview>`

```
<webview src="http://my-website/foo.html" useragent="MyFakeAgent/1.0"></webview>
```

3) Using the `onBeforeSendHeaders` callback in the main process

```
import { session } from 'electron';

session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {
    details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = 'MyFakeAgent/1.0';
    callback({
        cancel: false,
        requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which handles all webview instances in a BrowserWindow (which is called `mainWindow` in the code below).

```js
    const getUserAgentString = () => {
      let userAgentString = 'ElectronApp/' + app.getVersion()
      userAgentString += " Electron/" + process.versions.electron
      userAgentString += " Chrome/" + process.versions.chrome
      userAgentString += " Node.js/" + process.versions.node
      return userAgentString
    }
    //where mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(browserWindowOptions)
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-attach-webview', function (event, webContents) {
        webContents.userAgent = getUserAgentString()
    })
```